# Changing "editor.foreground" color in VS Code does not seem to be working in all cases

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, themes, customization

I noticed that when I am adding new lines to a file sometimes the font color is unreadable.

[example of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuUt5.png)

It doesn't occur in all cases but I notice it most when adding new lines inside structs, functions, etc. When I run the **Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scope** I see "`No theme selector`" so I added a specification for `editor.foreground` to `workbench.colorCustomizations` and then the inspection command shows the foreground color I set, but the text did not change color.

[example of inspector showing different foreground color than what is rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09SZg.png)

I haven't been able to identify exactly when this will occur but I do notice if I navigate away from a file where it is occurring and then navigate back it will correct itself most of the time. If I add a second new line the first will also usually correct to what the inspector says the foreground is supposed to be. Saving the file doesn't seem to immediately change the font color. I have seen this occurring with files in multiple different languages and on every single theme I have tried.

Version: 1.79.2 (Universal)
Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
Date: 2023-06-14T08:58:52.392Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.4.0

Comment: please provide details to reproduce the problem in as simple of a way as you can find. see the instructions on providing a [mre]. Are you using any protobuf extensions? Does this occur outside of protobuf files? Does it only occur in specific parts of protobuf files?

Comment: As I mentioned, it does occur in files of multiple languages, even languages I don't have any extensions installed for. For example, when I went to add the `editor.foreground` line in my `settings.json` it occurred with that line. I haven't been able to confirm exactly when it happens but it seems to happen most often in multi-line blocks. In JSON I see it if I add any line inside of the outermost braces. With protobuf files it seems to happen inside service/rpc/message blocks. I've also seen it in Go files both in and out of existing code blocks.

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. 2) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: It seems to be a bug with the VSCode Neovim extension. I'm filing a bug report now. Thanks! (edit: I see there already was a bug report that seems to be the same issue? https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/issues/131)